# Printing Out Characters in Ada

Tags: string, character, ada

I have these declared:

```
  subtype Num_Char          is Natural 
     range 1 .. Definitions.Page_Width + 1;
  subtype Number_Of_Rows    is Definitions.Number_Of_Rows;
  type Chars                is array (Number_Of_Rows, Num_Char) of Character; 
  The_Chars           : Chars;
```

What is the best way to print this out to the screen using Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line()?

Comment: Why is the number of characters in each row one more than the defined `Tote_Page_Width`?

Comment: Good question.. Not sure  (Took that from some existing code)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you want to use `Ada.Text_IO` and not just `Put_Line` specifically, and assuming that `Number_Of_Rows` is meant to be an integer range like `Num_Char`, that would be

```
for R in The_Chars'Range (1) loop
   for C in The_Chars'Range (2) loop
      Ada.Text_IO.Put (The_Chars (R, C));
   end loop;
   Ada.Text_IO.New_Line;
end loop;
```

Answer (score 3):

A lot of problems in Ada actually go back to your initial choice of types. So personally, I'd suggest a slight rewrite to make your life easier:

```
subtype Row is String (1..Definitions.Tote_Page_Width + 1);
type Chars is array (Definitions.Number_Of_Rows) of Row;
```

Now you *could* write this out with the following:

```
for I in The_Chars'range loop
    Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line (The_Chars (I));
end loop;
```

However, there is still a big problem here. `Put_Line` will print out **all** the characters in each row. Ada strings are not null-terminated, so if there unused data at the end of some of your lines, that will get printed too.

There are lots of ways to deal with this, but they are very different techniques than would be used to handle C strings. If you try to handle Ada strings like you'd handle C strings, you will drive yourself nuts.

For this reason, I would dearly like to see your code that actually *fills* `The_Char` with data (and the rationale behind it).